# Backbone.js Events and Collections - one View per Item

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Collection of Items. Each Item has its own View and when rendered, creates a `<div>` containing a `<a href>` element. Each Item in a View can itself be a Collection. The View defines an event, for example:

```
events: {"click div. a": "foo"},
```

The resulting HTML of rendering a Collection with a single Item, which itself is is a Collection of three items is:

```
<div><a href>One</a>
  <div><a href>Two</a></div>
  <div><a href>Three</a></div>
  <div><a href>Four</a></div>
</div>
```

Clicking `<a href>One</a>` works fine, and a single event is triggered and I have access to the model from within the View.  However:

- Clicking `<a href>Two</a>` results in the event being triggered for
  Two, Three, Four and One.
- Clicking `<a href>Four</a>` results in the event being triggered for
  Two, Three, Four and One
- Clicking `<a href>Three</a>` results in the event being triggered for
  Two, Three, Four and One

The general pattern is clicking on a nested `<a href>` element will call the event handler for all **sibling** and **parent** `<a href>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to change your event registration:

```
events: {"click div > a": "foo"}
```

Comment: How can I register for an event for a specific View instance, when they are generated from the same View 'class'?